# Fetch Document Library Asset Changes from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, graph-api

I want to fetch events from SharePoint which can indicate file changes in document library after given timestamp.
When i say Changes, I mean

1. All Created/New Files
2. Updated files
3. Deleted files and folders
4. Renamed files and folders
5. Moved files and folders

Is there any API that can help me achieve this?
I have explored SharePoint's REST API, and i wasn't able to find any endpoint that can help me fetch move, renamed, deleted files(or events).

I know there is MS Graph API's delta feature, using which we can list changes. Can anyone share how to use it with SharePoint site and document library.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{domainName}:/sites/{siteName}
```

**Note: Given relative folder path of document library and timestamp. Fetch/Query changes after timestamp for given folder path.**